# how to replace SID in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

i have installed `oracle 11g` on `windows 7` but it was not installed properly when i tried to install again i'm getting a message that

```
the SID is already existed in the machine so replace it
```

I'm unable to install now so please help me

Comment: Hey, we're going to need some more information.. can you update with the steps you followed to install?  ie. where you downloaded, etc...

Comment: can you include the *exact* error too please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do not need to keep and data from the failed install.  If yes, you should do a data pump export ( expdp ) first.

You need to drop the existing database SID.  Click Start, look for your Oracle Home folder, click Configuration and Management Tools folder, click Data Configuration Assistant, click Next, choose Delete a Database, choose your SID and continue.  Ignore the warning ( if you get it ) about not being able to connect to the database and continue.  That will remove the services and allow you to re-install using the same SID.